# Ruby Dir.glob issue only on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, glob, dir, ruby-2.1

This line:

```
dirs = Dir.glob(some_file_path + '/' + '**' + '/')
```

works as it should on OSX and linux. The same line on Windows:

```
dirs = Dir.glob(some_file_path + '\\' + '**' + '\\')
```

returns no directories. What am I  doing wrong?

I'm trying to get an array of all of a folders sub folders recursively, and the code above works really nice on a *nix system is there something I need to do differently on windows?

Also note: that on all operating systems I'm using ruby 2.1.5.

Comment: You need to escape the backslash.

Comment: August, I wrote the post really quickly. In my code the slashes are escaped like this '\\'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the '/' will work on Windows as well (Ruby is smart for this).

Comment: Unfortunately that did not change anything. :-(

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Can you provide some context of what some_file_path contains? What value?

Comment: C:\Users\alex\Desktop\homes

and below that is some folders and within those folders are files and folders.

Comment: So what are you trying to display exactly? All the files inside some_file_path or?

Comment: You were right, sorry about that the file paths in my yml file were using \ not / changing them there fixed the issue.